# Confusion about callback and registering a callback (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, asynccallback

I am new to using callbacks in C++. I found some terms related to callbacks and it is making me confused. I want to know the details about callback and registering a callback in C++. Are they both the same? Are they different? When and how to use each one? I will be grateful if anyone can help me understand these with simple examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically registering call back is lower left arrow in this picture:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29#/media/File:Callback-notitle.svg
And callback itself is either lower right arrow or the rightmost function, depending on context. Full wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: I am new to this. Can you please elaborate if possible? The image is not making so much sense to me. @Slimak

Comment: When and how each one is used? An example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There is much more information in the linked article. Let me know if you have some specific questions regarding contents of that article, especially regarding "Implementation" section of that article.

Comment: I understood the basic concept of callback functions. But is registering a callback is same as a callback? Or is it we need to before using callbacks?

Comment: Registering a callback is telling somebody what should be called back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of real life scenario. We have Alice who wants to receive package from Shop as soon as possible, but does not want to wait in the Shop until the package is ready. But Alice has a friend, Bob, who has lots of time and can wait in the Shop. So Alice comes with Bob to the shop and says, hey prepare a package for me, and give it to Bob when it is ready. In this scenario Shop is external service, Bob is callback, and Alice saying that package shall be given to Bob is registering callback, and Shop giving package to Bob is executing callback.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::literals;

void Bob(const char* what)
{
        std::cout << "Bob received:" << what << "\n";
}
void Shop(void(callback)(const char*))
{
        std::cout << "Shop is very busy with preparing packagae\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
        std::cout << "Package ready, Shop will execute callback\n";
        callback("package");
}
void Alice()
{
        std::cout << "Alice will register callback at Shop (and start Shop BTW)\n";
        std::thread prepare_package(Shop, Bob);
        std::cout << "Alice can do something else\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        std::cout << "Alice still can do something else\n";
        prepare_package.join();
}
int main()
{
        Alice();
}
```

Comment: So, every callback function needs registering. Am I right?

Comment: Well depends on what you mean "every" --- every execution or every function. You can agree with Shop, that Bobs leaves there to receive multiple parcels --- then you register Bob once, but it will be executed multiple times. Or you may have agreement with Shop, that for each parcel you need again to tell them that it is Bob to receive the package --- depends on how Shop works.